# why there is no output in java even after using system.out.println function?

Tags: java

```
  class PrimeTernary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, m;
        int n = 8;
        m = n / 2;
        String result;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            System.out.println("Not prime number");
        else
            for (i = 3; i <= m; i++) {
                result = (n % i == 0) ? "not prime" : "prime";
                System.out.println(result);
            }
    }
}
```

what is wrong in my code? Can anyone pleased to explain it in brief?

Comment: You set `n = 8`. Meaning it is neither `0` nor `1` and the whole `if` with the rest of the code gets skipped.

Comment: Check your conditions first. It's faulty.

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? Are you trying to check if given number is prime or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Even if `n` is 0 or 1 (only then your print statement could ever be reached), then `m` is necessarily 0. This means, the `for` loop does not run.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is never true since `n` is always 8.

`if (n == 0 || n == 1)` is the same as `if (8 == 0 || 8 == 1)`

So your loop will never execute.